# How to do statistical classification on an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, statistics, classification

I've got a bunch of numbers in an array and I need to do some statistics on them. I need to know how many of each number there are in the array.

Here's the array:

```
myArray =
[2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 76, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 89, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 105, 105, 105, 106, 107, 107, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 116, 116, 117, 118, 120, 121, 121, 121, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 132, 133, 133, 134, 134, 134, 136, 136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 140, 141, 141, 142, 142, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 145, 150, 150, 153, 155, 159, 160, 160, 161, 162, 164, 164, 166, 176, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181, 187, 191, 192, 193, 194, 197, 200, 203, 211, 216, 224, 251, 280, 333]
```

Here's what I'm using to parse through it currently (which is not working very well):

```
    for (var key in myArray){
        var obj = myArray[key];

        var count = 0;
        while(obj < 30){
            myArrayStats[0] = count;
            obj++;
        }
        while(obj > 30 && obj < 40){
            myArrayStats[1] = count;
            obj++;
        }
        //etc....
    }
```

Creating a new array using object literals would be much nicer and easier to use, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I guess you wanted something more like
if (obj < 30) {
  myArrayStats[0] = (myArrayStats[0] || 0) + 1;
} else if (obj >= 30 && obj < 40) {
  myArrayStats[1] = (myArrayStats[1] || 0) + 1;
} etc?? Anyway, hope the answers below clear it up.

Comment: In R, one would simply do `table(cut(myArray, c(0, 30, 40, Inf)))` and the result is (will probably get broken: `(0,30]  (30,40] (40,Inf]
 
     113       56      326`˛ :) You could add -Inf to have values smaller than zero on the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just works whether your array is sorted or not, but it shouldn't be much slower than any algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that it is sorted anyways:

```
var myArrayStats = [];
for(var i = myArray.length; i--;)
    myArrayStats[myArray[i]] = (myArrayStats[myArray[i]] || 0) + 1;

console.log(myArrayStats[6]);  // Outputs 7
console.log(myArrayStats[10]); // Outputs 5
console.log(myArrayStats[20]); // Outputs 5
```

If you want to do this for only a portion of the original array than use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the portion of the array you want and then do the same thing as above on that array:

```
var mySubArray = myArray.slice(0,30);
var myArrayStats = [];
for(var i = mySubArray.length; i--;)
    myArrayStats[mySubArray[i]] = (myArrayStats[mySubArray[i]] || 0) + 1;

console.log(myArrayStats[6]);  // Outputs 7
console.log(myArrayStats[9]);  // Outputs 7
console.log(myArrayStats[10]); // Outputs undefined
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost what I'm looking for. Now, how would I find only the number of items in a certain range for these values, between say 0 - 30, and 30 - 60, and 60 - 90 etc, similar to the while loop I used above? Could you increment by a value like 30?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have equally spaced bins and want to count how many values fall in each. Since this question was tagged with jQuery, let's use a utility function from that to avoid an explicit loop to show another way to do things. (I guess PaulPRO's approach is superior though.)

```
function hist(values, min, max, numBins) {
    var bins = [];
    var range = max - min;
    jQuery.each(values, function(i, value) {
        var bin = Math.floor(numBins * (value - min) / range);
        bin = Math.min(Math.max(bin, -1), numBins) + 1;
        bins[bin] = (bins[bin] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return bins;
}
```

We can exercise the above code with the following:

```
function consoleHist(values, min, max, numBins) {
    var bins = hist(values, min, max, numBins);
    var step = (max - min) / numBins;
    jQuery.each(bins, function(i, count) {
        var lower = (i - 1) * step + min;
        var upper = lower + step;
        if (lower < min) {
            lower = -Infinity;
        }
        if (upper > max) {
            upper = Infinity;
        }
        console.log('[' + lower + ', ' + upper + '): ' + (count || 0));
    });
}

consoleHist([-10, 0, 11, 29, 30, 59, 60, 1000], 0, 60, 2);
```

Produces the following output on the console:

```
[-Infinity, 0): 1
[0, 30): 3
[30, 60): 2
[60, Infinity): 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myArray = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8,
  8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11,
  11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14]

for (var a = myArray, b = {}, i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) b[a[i]] ? b[a[i]]++ : b[a[i]] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(b)
  .map(function(c) {
    return [c, b[c]]
  })));
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your first answer on Stack Overflow! It looks good, but you could make it even better by adding some text to explain how your solution works.